# Drupal 7 hook block title from views module

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-modules

I have views that shows profiles of my site within a block.
Now, I am trying to alter the title of that block through hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter.
here is the code of my custom module:

```
<?php
function homepagefilter_block_view_views_new_users_alter(&$data, $block) {
$data['subject'] = t('New title of the block');
}
```

I doen't see any effect on the block title...
Why is that?

Comment: Do a dpm($data), if your running devel, or var_dump($data) and make sure the module is actually executing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try hook_block_view_alter().

```
function homepagefilter_block_view_alter(&$data, $block){
  if($block->delta == 'BLOCKID'){
    print_r($block);
    print_r($data['subject']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The deltas of blocks created by the Views module looks like "[view_name]-[display_name]", and the display name is something like "[type]_[number]" by default. So that means the full delta for your block is probably something like "new_users-block_1". However, you can't implement homepagefilter_block_view_views_new_users-block_1_alter(), because you can't use a hyphen in a function name. The blocks Menu module creates has a similar problem ([see this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1076132)). As Behzad says, you'll have to implement the generic hook_block_view_alter() hook for now.